# How to get the center coordinates of the screen in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the x and y coordinates of the center of the screen. Here is what i tried:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
height = size.y;
float centerY=height/2;//i expect this is the y coordinate of center
```

But this does not work, when i say:

```
SomeImageView.setY(centerY);
```

I do not see it at the center of the screen. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're correctly getting the center coordinates, but `setY` is setting the position of the bottom edge of your `ImageView`. Off the top of my head, you may try something like

```
SomeImageView.setY(height - SomeImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight());
```

Comment: Thank you, that works but it is setting the top edge, and we do not need to divide intrinsic height ino two, i mean the following worked:

SomeImageView.setY((height - SomeImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()));

Comment: Yeah I usually need some trial & error with that, glad you figured it out :) (and I'm correcting my answer)