# Get the center coordinates of phone screen

Tags: java, android, coordinates

Can someone give me an example of how to get the center coordinates of the current displayed screen? I would like my objects to always be relative to the center coordinates of the active view.

Comment: Do you want coordinates or why can't you use center gravity?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm open to any suggestions, I am new to android app development. I have an iOS app that does it, but I'm interested in the least complex equivalent for android.

Comment: Assuming you just want to center a view, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499258/how-to-center-a-view-inside-of-an-android-layout

Comment: @cricket_007 I really want the coordinate. I am moving an object about the x-axis; so I want to keep it within a certain range +/-[some value] of the screen center x-coordinate.

Comment: [Get the screen dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520718/how-to-get-screen-width-and-height) and divide by 2, then?

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18304520/3678308

Comment: @cricket_007 Your solution worked, do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### You can try with `DisplayMetrics` to achieve your solution

```
int mWidth= this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int mHeight= this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Comment: Probably this doesn't give you full height if keyboard is open.

Comment: @Gupta , one simple solution for that would setting the activity to never resize with keyboard (in the manifest)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I resolved the issue.  As a background, I have a button that once the user moves the map to the desired location (cross hairs showing the centre of map) they can tap the button and a marker appears in the centre of the map.

```
findViewById(R.id.addMarker).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public  void onClick(View view) {
                    if(myMap != null){
                        double myLat = myMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
                        double myLng = myMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;
                        LatLng markerPoint = new LatLng(myLat, myLng);
                        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerPoint)).setTitle("new marker");
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

`int cx =screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int cy =   screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
float finalRadius = (float) Math.sqrt(cx * cx + cy * cy);`

float is the center if the object